# How to determine the maximum voltage and current ratings of a peltier element?

Tags: peltier, maximum-ratings

I recently bought a peltier with no ratings. None at all. On hindsight, it was probably not the smartest thing to do, but is there any way I can determine the maximum voltge and current values at which it can work? I know it works with a 9V battery.

I'm planning on feeding it with a variable power supply and keep on increasing the voltage, but how will I know when to stop? Any way to distinguish maximum point of peltier?

Comment: Found the specs. Question may be deleted... http://www.ge.infn.it/ATLAS/Electronics/Humidity/Peltier/peltier%20RS.pdf

Comment: You can delete unanswered question if you have found the solution or you can post your own answer to help others.